# How do I find which hardware RAID array my server is running?

Tags: dell, windows

Dell VIRTUAL DISK SCSI Disk Device is the name of an array in the device manager(Under Disk Drives) of my server. While I know that "Dell VIRTUAL DISK SCSI Disk Device" indicates that I am running a hardware array, I would like to know which RAID I am running (ie., RAID 0, RAID 1...etc.)

And is there any possible way that I can check the RAID version without restarting the machine? I am taking over a server without any documentation. Any help would be appreciated :).

FYI the server is a Dell PowerEdge 840.

Comment: It may help to add any research you've already done, what you've tried etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download and install Dell OpenManage Server Administrator (DOMSA) on the server.

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/poweredge-840?driverId=G2WT6&osCode=WS8R2&fileId=2883471492&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM

That will let you see the RAID configuration of the virtual disk from within DOMSA.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But is there anyway to see the RAID version without installing any software? Thanks

Comment: No. You need access to the hardware and you can't get that from within Windows without DOMSA.